# wordpress não mostra posts de acordo com tag ou categoria

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou desenvolvendo um tema para WordPress, e recebo o erro `404`. Tenho um post com certa categoria, e consigo acessá-lo normalmente por seu permalink. Porém ao acessar via sua `categoria` ou `tag`, nenhum resultado é retornado.

Já tentei instalar o WordPress novamente no servidor, até usei temas padrão, mas nada disso solucionou o problema.

Comment: Pode dar mais detalhes? Qual estruturas de permalinks você está usando? Essas categorias/tags foram criadas por código ou direto no painel? Você criou um template de arquivo? Está criando um tema filho? etc....

Comment: Você tentou fazer um flush das suas regras de permalink? (i.e., salvá-las novamente). Verificou também o `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o problema foi resolvido através do próprio painel administrativo do `wordpress` os links permanentes não estavam atualizados, apenas selecionei outra opção de link permanente e tudo foi resolvido!